# Change default echo in Windows CMD

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd

I'm using UnxUtils for running Bash commands in Windows CMD. Bash files are stored in `C:\Users\username\win_bash\`. I have added that folder to windows PATH so I can access it from cmd no mater in which folder am I. I would like to overwrite default Windows `echo` command. Currently I can do that with specifying whole path to the Bash `echo` command: `C:\Users\win_bash\echo.exe`. Can I make Bash's `echo` default, so I could just type echo without the whole path to the command?

Comment: In bash `echo` is a built-in. It also exists and external program for POSIX reasons, but that version is effectively never used unless explicitly called.

Comment: Well, it is possible to define with `%SystemRoot%\System32\doskey.exe echo=C:\Users\win_bash\echo.exe $*` to run `echo.exe` with passing the arguments to this executable instead of running the internal command `echo` of `cmd.exe`. But the internal command `echo` is different in argument parsing than running executables because of strings containing a space or one of these characters ``()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` must not be enclosed in `"` which is necessary on passing such a string to an executable to run by `cmd.exe`. Just characters like `&<>|` to output by command `echo` must be escaped with `^`.

Comment: Therefore I would expect lots of troubles on replacing the internal command `echo` of `cmd.exe` by a `doskey` macro even on doing that just for the command prompt window or for some batch files. However, you can use that if you want and it works for you for at least those use cases where you think the usage of `echo.exe` is better than the usage of Windows command `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can change the system path look for the default path after EDITING the default path you can change or remove the system variable

EDIT path with `C:\Users\win_bash\echo.exe`

---

I'm an Linux user you have try this solution below, Make sure to copy the default path and setting before applying changes so you can revert back if anything goes wrong.

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html

Comment: You don't add executables to the `%path%`, but folders to search for executables. In `cmd`, `echo` is an internal command, which will be executed without searching for an executable with the same name. The only way to use an external "echo" is to use `"echo.exe" string` (yes, including the quotes (works only when `echo.exe` is in the current working folder or anywhere within the `%path%`; else full path (like in the question) is required)). Without quotes `echo.exe string` will echo `exe string` (using the internal `echo` command))

Comment: `"echo"`(without .exe) is also working. You should put this as answer xD